# Cedarview Video Driver Doesn't work with Intel DN2800MT Motherboard

Tags: intel-graphics, cedarview

I updated my computer today with the latest kernel and video driver for the Cedarview Chipset by Intel and after I reboot I only see vertical stripes on the monitor. I also tried using the VNC Viewer to login to the system and the connection is refused. I have seen some aricles about custom edits to the ubuntu configuration. Does anyone know how I can modify the latest updates to get it working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem a few minutes ago. The problem is with the PAE linux kernel.

This should fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-.*generic-pae linux-image-.*generic-pae
```